# Using __init__ and inheritance in python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, ironpython

I'm a little confused regarding using `__init__` and inheritance and would love to get some help with it.

I have a class [that can not be changed]:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, param1 = 7, param2 = 10):
        self.x = param1
        self.y = param2     
    def func1(self):
        op1()
        op2()
    def func2(self):
        pass
```

this is some class that was written and I'm using it when overloading its functions:

```
class B(A):
    def func1(self)
        op3()
        op4()
    def func2(self)
        op5()
```

My problem starts here : I want to use Class B several times and sent each time different parameter:

```
---new .py file: ---
def myFunction():
    myInstance = B()
```

I want to do something like :

```
def myFunction():
    myInstance = B(40,"test")
```

I thought adding to B class - `__init__` but the problem is that now I'm not sure what `self` it would use :
explanation : 
Inside B class I have overloaded `func2(self)`
I thought writing :

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, paramNumber, paramString)
        self.paramNumber = paramNumber
        self.paramString = paramString
```

but now in `func2(self)` , what `self` is used? the new one? the old one? will it work?
meaning I will have : `self.x , self.y and self.paramNumber self.parmString ?`they are different "selfs"

Editing :
Should I use super as well?

```
    class B(A):
    def __init__(self, paramNumber, paramString,param1, param2)
        self.paramNumber = paramNumber
        self.paramString = paramString
        super(B,self).__init__(param1,param2)

    def myFunction():
       myInstance = B(40,"test")
       // I will get : self.x = 7
       // self.y= 10
       // self.paramNumber=40
       //self.paramString = "test"
```

is this the correct solution?

Comment: They're the same `self`, but you've forgotten to call `A.__init__` to set up `.x` and `.y`

Comment: Don't call `A.__init__` directly as Eric mentions.  Use [super](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super).

Comment: so wait - I need to add to my "def __init__(self,paramNumber, paramString) after setting this init, also the super??

Comment: All methods of an object have the same `self`. It doesn't matter which class the methods come from; there aren't an `A` self and a `B` self you have to distinguish between.

Comment: why? If I'm using __init__ is B class with self.xx and self.yy then how can I still reach self.x and self.y [ from A]

Answer (score 3):

So basically you want to run `__init__` from parent class inside child:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, paramNumber, paramString):
        super(B, self).__init__(param1=1, param2=2)
        # the other code goes here
```

Comment: I first use super and then add seld.paramString and self.paramNumber? I edited my question to what I hope is correct - is it ?

Comment: @user1386966 The order depends. Just look at the code and figure it out. Sometimes you want to fire super at the begining, sometimes at the end. I suppose that in your case it will be at the begining.